# Laravel 8 Jetstream how to redirect user to custom route after resetting password

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel 8 jetstream for authentication. My question is, how can I redirect the user after resetting the password to the custom route? I don't want to redirect the user to the login page. I didn't find the route in all Fortify classes; I am sure it should override.

> protected $redirectTo

But I don't know in which file I have to do this change.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**EDIT**: It is not recommended to edit a file in vendor, use BillD's solution.

Check out `vendor\laravel\fortify\src\Http\Responses\PasswordResetResponse.php`

You should be able to modify the response in the method:

```
/**
     * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new JsonResponse(['message' => trans($this->status)], 200)
                    : redirect()->route('login')->with('status', trans($this->status));
    }
```

Comment: Editing a file in vendor is not recommended.

Comment: Agreed, the other solution is better.

Answer (score 6):

Here’s what I ended up doing to have a redirect back to the login route after a user submits a password reset action:

- Copy the file `SuccessfulPasswordResetLinkRequestResponse.php` from `\vendor\laravel\fortify\Http\Responses\` to a folder on your project at `app\Http\Responses`.
- In your new file `SuccessfulPasswordResetLinkRequestResponse.php`, change the namespace to:

```php
namespace App\Http\Responses;
```

- Open `app\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider.php`
- Inside the `boot()` function add:

```php
public function boot() 
{
    ...

    $this->app->singleton(SuccessfulPasswordResetLinkRequestResponseContract::class, SuccessfulPasswordResetLinkRequestResponse::class);
}
```

- In this same `FortifyServiceProvider.php` file, add the namespaces:

```php
use App\Http\Responses\SuccessfulPasswordResetLinkRequestResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\SuccessfulPasswordResetLinkRequestResponse as SuccessfulPasswordResetLinkRequestResponseContract;
```

- In your new `SuccessfulPasswordResetLinkRequestResponse.php` file, edit the `toResponse()` function:

```php
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse(['message' => trans($this->status)], 200)
            : redirect()->route('login')->with('status', trans($this->status));
    }
```

Here's a helpful link that shows all of the response classes that Fortify uses at the time of this writing:
[Overriding other Jetstream and Fortify functionality](https://laravel-news.com/override-login-redirects-in-jetstream-fortify)

Comment: This is better than the accepted solution!

Comment: Not sure if it's a difference with newer versions of Laravel, but the namespace and folder name for me is `App\Http\Response` rather than `Responses` (singular rather than plural)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue using jetstream and found the accepted solution is better especially if there are admin and user models each has reset password functionality,

You don't need to edit `PasswordResetResponse.php` in vendor but simply:

- copy it to `App\Http\Responses`
- then as you can find `/vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php`

```
Route::post('/reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
->middleware(['guest:' . config('fortify.guard')])
->name('password.update');
```

It points to `/laravel/fortify/src/Http/Controllers/NewPasswordController.php`.

Store function has the default `PasswordResetResponse.php`.

```
public function store(Request $request): Responsable
    {
        $request->validate([
            'token' => 'required',
            Fortify::email() => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

    
        $status = $this->broker()->reset(
            $request->only(Fortify::email(), 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'),
            function ($user) use ($request) {
                app(ResetsUserPasswords::class)->reset($user, $request->all());

                app(CompletePasswordReset::class)($this->guard, $user);
            }
        );

        return $status == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
            ? app(PasswordResetResponse::class, ['status' => $status])
            : app(FailedPasswordResetResponse::class, ['status' => $status]);
    }
```

So only need to change is the namespace in `NewPasswordController.php` file to point to your PasswordResetResponse.php you've made.

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\PasswordResetResponse; 
 To--
use App\Http\Responses\PasswordResetResponse;
```